# msi install certificates to currentuser

Tags: c#, certificate, windows-installer

I've a Visual Studio MSI Installer which should install my test certificate to the current user and my test CA  to root, local machine. But for current user it doesn't work. I get no error, but it isn't added to the other certificates.
My certificates are a embedded resources.

```
            using (Stream CertStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(GetType(), @"Resources.client_certificate.cer"))
            {
                byte[] RawBytes = new byte[CertStream.Length];
                for (int Index = 0; Index < CertStream.Length; Index++)
                {
                    RawBytes[Index] = (byte)CertStream.ReadByte();
                }

                X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(RawBytes);
                X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
                store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
                store.Add(cert);
                store.Close();
```

Do I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please be aware that Microsoft has deprecated that project type and it's not in VS2012.  Also if you move to another tool such as WindowsInstaler XML you'll find MSI extensions that make this easier without writing your own custom actions.  If you choose not to move to WiX you could build a merge module in WiX and merge it into your VDPROJ MSI.

[Certificate Element (Iis Extension)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12390123/msi-install-certificates-to-currentuser)

[Augmenting InstallShield using Windows Installer XML - Certificates](http://blog.iswix.com/2011/01/augmenting-installshield-using-windows_19.html)

Comment: deprecated? nice to know... really bad.

Comment: Not so bad IMO.  Anyone who understands MSI at the level of say someone understanding .NET at the MSIL level knows that VDRPOJ generated pretty bad installs.  They might work on most machines for most simple installs but the moment you do anything complicated it puts you down a pretty bad road with lots of problems.  Frankly it was a #FAIL and MSFT / DevDiv accepted that.

Comment: Maybe you are right, this is the first time I have to use installers. But now I have to spend more time, which I don't have, to understand WindowsInstaller XMl.

Comment: Well, I'd never spam StackOverflow but my services are available... :) http://blog.iswix.com/2012/09/visual-studio-deployment-projects.html

Comment: If you want an example of what a WiX project can look like download and install WiX 3.6 and IsWIX 1.5.12089.2.  Get a feel for what the IsWiX installer looks like (custom setup) and then browse the source at http://iswix.codeplex.com/SourceControl/BrowseLatest